# column layout for html form using css

Tags: html, forms, css

I need to create horizontal form where each field appearing under its label and form basically column format where label and field appear in one column.
I tried using it with table format but it doesn't go well with dynamic forms where I don't know the number of fields and label that will be present in form.

I searched and found
[HTML columns or rows for form layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040031/html-columns-or-rows-for-form-layout)
First approach gives with the horizontal layout but field and label don't appear aligned in column format.

```
.field-row {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.field-row span {
display: block;
width: 30%;
float: left;
}
.field-row .field-container {
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
}

<div class="field-row">
<span>Field 1</span>
<span>Field 2</span>
<span>Field 3</span>
<div class="field-container">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/) for above code.

Is it even possible to achieve this just divs or table is the only way?

**[Edit]** Sorry, for missing this in original question.

The label row needs to have a border around it in order to make it appear as single row.
That is the reason I kept all the labels in one div so that this style can be applied to the div.
Updated jsFiddle for the output expected

http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/7/

Comment: Do you want this type http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/1/ ???

Comment: No, this is vertical form. I need my form to appear horizontally each field appearing underneath label

Comment: Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/3/ 
you have to change in css like .field-row .field-container {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

Comment: The layout appears perfectly but I missed one thing in question. The label should have border around them making them appear as one row. Is is possible to do it with this structure?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/5/

Comment: it shows border around each label but I would need a border around the complete row. I updated the question to reflect the same

Comment: Here is the updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I add a new answer instead of amending the existing one, because your requirements have been changed or clarified since:

- your HTML code is generated, so you can't modify it.
- you need a border around the label row.

Please see the answer for both:
http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/13/

The tricky part is you need to set the width of the label and the input at the same time but the text input has a 1px border by default which includes in the width.
To work this around I added hidden border to the labels as well.

```
.field-row span{
border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this ?

```
.field {
   float: left;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/2/

Your HTML code doesn't respect the float and the logic of the HTML document : you should regroup elements of the same information unit (here : the label, and its input).

Answer (score 0):

Here is html code.

```
  <div class="field-row">
    <div class="field-container">
         <span>Field 1</span>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>

    <div class="field-container">
         <span>Field 2</span>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>

    <div class="field-container">
         <span>Field 3</span>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is css

```
.field-row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.field-row span {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.field-row .field-container {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.field-container span {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
display: block;
width: 93%;
}
```

Please see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/5/) link.

Please see my updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/12/)

Comment: This answers the original question but it doesn't allows border in the label row.

Answer (score 0):

Using css columns could be the easiest way.

See Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/8/**

```
.field-row {
    -moz-column-width: 128px;
    -webkit-column-width: 128px;
     -column-width: 128px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    column-gap: 0px;
}
label { display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }
input {
    width: 90%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Just make sure the width of the container doesn't get too small or too large. Otherwise, you may have to tweak the widths accordingly.

Another variation (*as per your comment above on borders*): **http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/10/**

And, this one uses `column-rule` to give it a table look: **http://jsfiddle.net/aBeF8/11/**

*Aside*: You should use `label`s with `for` instead of `span`s for labels.

Comment: The form is dynamically generated in an enterprise app. I cannot change to use label instead of span and not possible to use for also.

Comment: @Neel: in that case its ok. just replace *label* in the css with *span*. i have updated the answer to include another fiddle with borders.